# Нужны ли запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужны ли запятые в предложениях: *Лепешка с добавлением масла(,) диаметром 6 см, толщиной 1 см(,) с наколами в середине. Изделие с сыром(,) в виде лепешки или пирога*?

Answer (score 1):

(1) Лепешка с добавлением масла, диаметром 6 см, толщиной 1 см, с наколами в середине.

(2) Изделие с сыром в виде лепешки или пирога.

При обособлении несогласованных определений следует учитывать их семантику, а именно какой признак они обозначают - **отличительный или сопутствующий/дополнительный.**

(1) Обычно **первое определение задает основной признак**, далее следуют **дополнительные (обособленные) признаки** (всё это в достаточной мере условно, но позволяет построить удобную структуру предложения).

(2) Во втором предложении **оба определения входят в основное сообщение,** что  связано с нераспространенностью предложения.

Comment: Спасибо. Правильно ли я поняла, что если определения имеют дополнительный признак, то они всегда обособляются? А по второму предложению меня смущает, что получается как будто сыр в виде лепешки или пирога

Comment: Тогда  лучше поставить запятую, двусмысленность допускать нельзя.

Comment: А Вы могли бы подсказать,  в каком авторитетном учебнике / книге можно почитать об обособлении определений (согласованных, несогласованных, однородных и неоднородных) Розенталь и Лопатин не помогают в решении возникающих вопросов.

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть в справочнике Валгиной  Н. http://fanread.ru/book/4211248/